# Javascript slide toggle on hidden div not working

Tags: javascript, slidetoggle

I am using the Javascript below to slide toggle on a hidden DIV, but this i snot working, I must have the syntax wrong & can't seem to correct it.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
    function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("header-contact-form-wrap");
    var text = document.getElementById("request-a-quote");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-star-half-o'></i> Request a Quote";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "X Close";
    }
    $('#header-contact-form-wrap').slideToggle("slow");
} 
</script>
```

Comment: `.slideToggle()` is a jQuery method. do you have jQuery loaded on your page?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a **lot** of jQuery code. Do you have jQuery enabled? If not, include it in your code, like so:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
```

If you need a different build version, go to this site. https://code.jquery.com/jquery/